# CSS: Linear gradient background colours not applying

Tags: css, linear-gradients, webmail

Do linear gradient colours work in all browsers? I’m facing issue like, linear gradient colour(black with grey) working fine in outlook and gmail but it’s not working in web mail and mobile devices. How to get out of this issue? Thanks

Comment: use an image instead

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you have coded your css. It's best if you give all browser prefixes so that it will work across all browsers. For example like this

```
background-image:     -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:      -moz-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF);
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF);
background-image:      linear-gradient(right, #0c93C0, #FFF);
```

For Internet Explorer versions less than IE10 you should be using it like this:

```
/*IE7-*/ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0);
/*IE8+*/ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#0c93c0', endColorStr='#FFFFFF', GradientType=0)";
```

Also before you use it I suggest you see whether it is compatible in different browser version by using this: https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient